# Some easy way to turn all IMAP -devices silent in the same network while sleeping?

Tags: debian, android, imap, ipad, alarm

I have different IMAP devices such as Debian laptop, iPad and Android -phone. When I get email, they all start banging. How can I put them to silent mode automatically when I put alarm clock on?

Comment: For the debian laptop; look into `cron`. For the Android phone, assuming you use k9 (you should anyway), it has a setting for silent hours you can select.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any fast way, perhaps you need to put every device one-by-one to silent mode?

> **Android:** Silent Time [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.QuiteHypnotic.SilentTime&hl=en)
>   recommended by my friend.
>
> **Laptop:** Close the laptop -lid.
>
> **iPad:** Press the mute -button on the side (select settings and change the button to mute if not working).

But they are not optimal solutions, you waste time in putting things back.

*Novel idea: suppose devices are connected to the same Wireless-network, can you somehow turn them to silent mode by this network using NAT and providing some one-time-password?*

Comment: NAT does things, most notably packet routing between networks where one is unaware of the other. This is not one of those things. I think you must be thinking of something else.